# Formatting map axis labels in R to show latitude and longitude

Tags: r, dictionary, latitude-longitude, axes, axis-labels

I'm trying to draw a map in R with longitude and latitude labels on the axes.
I've used the following code to draw the map:

```
plot(countries, xlim=c(5,17), ylim=c(42,48),axes=FALSE)
#where xlim is the degrees east/west, and ylim north/south
```

On the plot I have suppressed the axes as I don't simply want them to say "5, 6, 7, etc...", I need them to say "5 degrees E, 6 degrees E..." where the "degrees" part is the degree symbol (i.e. superscript o).  The following script does this, but I want it to say "6 degrees E, 8 degrees E, etc..."

```
axis(1, at=c(6,8,10,12,14,16), labels=c(expression(6*degree),expression(8*degree),
expression(10*degree),expression(12*degree),expression(14*degree),
expression(16*degree)))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at `?degAxis` from the `sp` package

Answer (score 0):

This works, but I'm pretty sure it can be done in a more elegant way.

```
plot(c(), xlim=c(5,17), ylim=c(42,48),axes=FALSE)  
degs = seq(6,16,2)
```

Create a bquote string for each of the items, replacing `degree` with a symbol and `x` with a number from `degs`:

```
a = sapply(degs,function(x) bquote(.(x)*degree ~ E))
```

Call `expression` on each item in the list of bquotes:

```
axis(1, at=degs, lab=do.call(expression,a))
```

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely more elegant than my solution...

```
    axis(1, at=c(6,8,10,12,14,16), 
    labels=c(expression(paste(6*degree,"E")),expression(paste(8*degree,"E")),
    expression(paste(10*degree,"E")),expression(paste(12*degree,"E")),
    expression(paste(14*degree,"E")),expression(paste(16*degree,"E"))))
```

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
plot(shp, col="red", border="red", xlim=c(40.01,40.2), 
ylim=c(-1.6,-1.4), xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
plot(pw, add=TRUE, col="blue", border="blue")
sp::degAxis(side = 1, las=1, at = seq(40.01,40.2,0.05))
sp::degAxis(side = 2,las = 1, at=seq(-1.6,1.4,0.1))
box()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?